# CSS Grid - grid-template-areas behavior

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid defined by a grid-template-area. Can someone tell me why the following template won't work? I expect to see a 4x3 grid with equal sections. I have a fiddle demonstrating what happens as well as commented out styles for a grid that does work. I'm having trouble deciphering the difference between the 2 and why this one blows up. Thank you.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpqmtxe8/)

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-areas: "a b c d"
                         "b c d a"
                         "a b c d";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.container > header {
    grid-area: a;
}

.container > nav {
    grid-area: b;
}

.container > main {
    grid-area: c;
}

.container > footer {
    grid-area: d;
}
```

---

```
<div class="container">
    <header><h1>A</h1></header>
    <nav><h1>B</h1></nav>
    <main><h1>C</h1></main>
    <footer><h1>D</h1></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The second row is "b v d a" instead of "a b c d".

Comment: I want the second row to be in that order. I'm looking for 12 different equal sections.